# Convergence of $f_n(k) = k \ \text{(mod n)}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_n : \mathbb{N} \mapsto \mathbb{N}$ be a sequence of functions defined by $$f_n(k) = k \ \text{(mod n)}$$

Then which one of the following is true?

1. $(f_n)$ is not pointwise cgt.
2. $(f_n)$ is pointwise cgt to a bounded function.
3. $(f_n)$ is pointwise to a unbounded function.
4. $(f_n)$ is uniform on $\mathbb{N}$.

My attempt: $f_n(k) = \{0, 1, \cdots n-1\}$

Now I cannot proceed further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f_n$ is pointwise convergent to a $f(x)=x$ because for a fixed $x_0$, for every $N\ge x_0+1$, we get $|f_N(x_0)-f(x_0)|=0$. However, this is not uniformly convergent; in other words, for every $N$, take $x_0=N+1$. Then we have $|f_N(x_0)-f_{N+1}(x_0)|=1-0=1$, which implies the convergence is not uniform.

---

On [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence) you can read more about equivalent definitions of uniform convergence if needed.